# I want to find Cardinal direction (North, East, West, South) by given latitude and langitude in php

Tags: php

I want to find Cardinal direction (North, East, West, South) by given latitude and longitude in php, please prefer any php code

I tried

```
$lat1="43.8704455";         
$lon1="-79.4508084";

$lat2="43.7607414";         
$lon2="-79.4873425";

$x = ($lon2-$lon1) * cos(($lat1+$lat2)/2);
$y = ($lat2-$lat1);

$angle=atan2($y/$x);
```

Comment: So, you tried that code. What was the outcome?

Answer (score -1):

Try this, based on Haversine formula

```php
function getCardinalDirection($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2) {
    $dLat = deg2rad($lat2 - $lat1);
    $dLon = deg2rad($lon2 - $lon1);

    $y = sin($dLon) * cos(deg2rad($lat2));
    $x = cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) -
         sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos($dLon);
    $brng = atan2($y, $x);

    $brng = rad2deg($brng);
    $brng = ($brng + 360) % 360;

    $cardinalDirections = array('N', 'NE', 'E', 'SE', 'S', 'SW', 'W', 'NW', 'N');
    $dirIndex = round(($brng / 45));
    return $cardinalDirections[$dirIndex];
}
```

```php
$lat1 = 37.7749;
$lon1 = -122.4194;
$lat2 = 40.7128;
$lon2 = -74.0060;

$direction = getCardinalDirection($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2);

echo "The cardinal direction from ($lat1, $lon1) to ($lat2, $lon2) is: " . $direction;
```